# What is the correct term for sets that dont contain other sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

As the title asks, what is the correct term for a set that don't contain another set?

I have called them "flat" but what is the correct term?

Comment: are you talking about null-set. I am not too sure myself.

Comment: I don't think null-set is correct either.
I am looking for a label which applies to {2, 3} and not to {{2}, {3}}, because the set contains sets itself ({2} and {3}).

Comment: Do you mean a set where the elements are not sets?

Comment: Yes @Arctic Char, that is precisely what I mean

Comment: It depends what kind of set theory you are working with. In ZF, there is only the empty set, because numbers (like everything else) are sets too.

Comment: @Captain Lama, I am not totally sure.
But I know it is a geometry where numbers are not sets but atomic values, and the can be combined to a set of values.

Comment: Why would there be a name for that?  Is there a name for sets that do not contain any even numbers, or do not contain elephants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not heard of any term for this in particular. But the term [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) is used for elements that are not sets, so you could call your set a *set of urelements*.

One warning though: As you can see by following that link, the standard ZF axioms of set theory are formulated in such a way that urelements do not exist, i.e. everything is a set, and therefore (as said in the comments) the only set whose elements are not sets is the empty set. The reason for this formulation is explained in that link: "the urelements were not needed because they can easily be modeled in a set theory without urelements."

One thing to keep in mind: in analysis or geometry, it is not of particular importance whether numbers are or are not sets. Nonetheless, when analysis and geometry are modelled using the standard ZF axioms of set theory, every number *is* a set, every geometric point *is* a set, and so on.

You might be interested, for example, in the [Von Neumann definition of the natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Ordinals_extend_the_natural_numbers), which is formulated in set theory. And perhaps you already know how one can, [within set theory, use the natural numbers to form the integers, the integers to form the rationals, and the rationals to form the reals](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/ccs_proofs_f2014/ccs_proofs_f2014_lecture5.pdf). And, of course, one can use the reals to form the points of the Euclidean plane and so on.